# Name of a constant given its value

Tags: go

How do you get the name of a constant given its value ?

More specifically (and to get a more readable understanding), I'm working with the `crypto/tls` package. Cipher suites are defined as constants:

```
const (
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA            uint16 = 0x0005
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       uint16 = 0x000a
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        uint16 = 0x002f
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        uint16 = 0x0035
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA      uint16 = 0xc011
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA uint16 = 0xc012
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  uint16 = 0xc013
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  uint16 = 0xc014
)
```

After a successful handshake with a server, I can get to the Ciphersuite agreed on through the connection:

```
c, _ := tls.Dial("tcp", "somedomain.com:443", nil)
// Suppose everything went right

// This is the Ciphersuite for the conn:
cipher := c.ConnectionState().Ciphersuite
```

`cipher` here is an uint16. Is there a way to display it as a string, for instance `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` if that's what was agreed upon ?

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants presents exactly that, for their custom `ByteSize` type. If you can define your own `Cipher` type, you can add the same kind of string information (although you still have to type it all as strings)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am afraid that is not possible.
The constants are resolved at compile time and there is nothing in the `reflect` package that allows you to retrieve the name.

What I suggest is creating a map with the names:

```
var constLookup = map[uint16]string{
    tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:      `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`,
    tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA: `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. Bur as jimt and Valentin CLEMENT points out, sometimes it can be worth redeclaring the constants with your own type. If you just need to make a lookup, a map is fine. But choose what suits you.

Answer (score 33):

**Note**: As of Go 1.4, the `String()` code below can be auto-generated using Go's new `generate` feature, combined with the `stringer` command. [See here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) for more info.

Apart from ANisus' answer, you can do the following.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "crypto/tls"

type Ciphersuite uint16

const (
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA            = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA)
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA      = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA)
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  = Ciphersuite(tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
)

func (cs Ciphersuite) String() string {
    switch cs {
    case TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:
        return "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
    case TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
    case TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
    case TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    case TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:
        return "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
    case TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
    case TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
    case TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:
        return "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    }
    return "Unknown"
}

func main() {
    cs := TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    fmt.Printf("0x%04x = %s\n", uint16(cs), cs)

    cs = TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    fmt.Printf("0x%04x = %s\n", uint16(cs), cs)

    cs = TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    fmt.Printf("0x%04x = %s\n", uint16(cs), cs)
}
```

You can test it on the [go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JAQNr-z9NI).

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`go generate`](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to have this generated for you.

Install `stringer` using

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer
```

Now define a `type` for your `const`. You can do it like this

```
type TLSType uint16
const (
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA            TLSType = 0x0005
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       TLSType = 0x000a
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        TLSType = 0x002f
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        TLSType = 0x0035
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA      TLSType = 0xc011
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLSType = 0xc012
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  TLSType = 0xc013
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  TLSType = 0xc014
)
```

Then add this line to your file (spacing is important)

```
//go:generate stringer -type=TLSType
```

Now go to the terminal in the folder where your program is and run

```
go generate
```

This will create a file called `tlstype_string.go` in your code directory, which is the generated code that implements the `fmt.Stringer` interface for your `TLSType`. Open it if you want to see the implementation but you don't need to. It will just work.

Now when you run `go build` or `go run *.go` on this directory, your source files will use the generated code.

The full program would look something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//go:generate stringer -type=TLSType
type TLSType uint16

const (
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA            TLSType = 0x0005
    TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       TLSType = 0x000a
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        TLSType = 0x002f
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        TLSType = 0x0035
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA      TLSType = 0xc011
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA TLSType = 0xc012
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  TLSType = 0xc013
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  TLSType = 0xc014
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This const will be printed with its name instead of its number:")
    fmt.Println(TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("So will this one:")
    fmt.Println(TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Or maybe we want to give it a value and convert:")
    fmt.Println(TLSType(0xc011))
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("No problem:")
    fmt.Println(TLSType(0xc013))
}
```

Which outputs

```
This const will be printed with its name instead of its number:
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

So will this one:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Or maybe we want to give it a value and convert:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

No problem:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

If you add new `const` values, just run `go generate` again to update the generated code.