# What is the best practice to define a group of constant numbers with their description

Tags: go

For example, I just want to define a group of days with their names:

```
[
    {Monday=1, 'Monday'},
    {Tuesday=2, 'Tuesday'},
    {Thursday=3, 'Thursday'},
    ...
    {Sunday=4, 'Sunday'},
]
```

Here are the methods I known:

1. define a type and its desc() function.

```golang
type MyDay int
const (
    Monday MyDay = 0
    Tuesday MyDay = 1
)
func (d MyDay) desc() string {
    switch(d) {
    case Monday: return "Monday";
    case Tuesday: return "Tuesday"
    }
}
```

2. use an integer to string map

```golang
const (
    Monday int = 0
    Tuesday int = 1
)
var dayDescs []string {
    Monday: "Monday",
    Tuesday: "Tuesday",
}
```

Both them have a shortage. If I want to add a day, I must modify two places. If I just add it at one place, it can not work.

I known another ways is to use tags, but reflection will take side effect on efficient.

Is there a simple way to declare a constant integer with its description together?

Comment: Use the [stringer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) command with `go generate`.   See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43150489/5728991), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27187241/5728991)

Comment: stringer via go generate (as suggested) does this for you, but it is best to define your your string representation method as `String() string`, rather than any other signature, as this [stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface is used in many places such as `fmt`

Comment: @MuffinTop , it seems be a precompile method. If I can not find a native language solution, I will try it. Thank u very much!

Comment: @HymnsForDiscon , my concern is that if I add a new element to the group, I have to modify two places. If the number of elements is huge, to maintance it will cost lots of time.

Comment: @ProgQuester Go's [stringer](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) command is not part of the language proper, but the command is supported by the Go team and the command is used by the Go standard library.  See [Generating Code](https://blog.golang.org/generate) for more info on the command and how it works with the `go` tool.

Comment: See the time package's [Weekday type](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=11121:11137#L304).

Comment: See also the [regexp/syntax Op type](https://golang.org/src/regexp/syntax/op_string.go).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to implement `stringer` interface `String() string` method.

```
type MyDay int

const (
    Monday MyDay = iota
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
    Sunday
)

func (d MyDay) String() string {
    return []string{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}[d]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Monday.String())
}
```

Comment: If an Octday is to be insert to the group, still two lines need to be modify synchronously. If the group has large of elements, how to make the order correctly is a problem.

Comment: This is almost identical to how the standard library implements the [Weekday type](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=11121:11137#L304). In Go's implementation, an array (fixed size) is used instead of a string slice.

Comment: @ProgQuester I think there isnt any cleaner way. Still editing this code is simpler than other implementations. and since usually you write the definition and String() together you dont have to navigate so far.